# Moment js undefined Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I'm trying to use moment.js in my laravel project, not using vue, but still importing the package via npm.

My app.js file:

```
require('moment/moment.js');
require('./bootstrap');
require('bootstrap-select');
```

in my webpack.pix.js file looks like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');    

mix.setResourceRoot('laravel/public');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
     .combine([
          'resources/theme/dist/js/app.js',
          'resources/theme/dist/js/app.init.js',
          'resources/theme/dist/js/sidebarmenu.js',
          'resources/theme/dist/js/waves.js',
          'resources/theme/assets/libs/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js',    
          'resources/theme/assets/extra-libs/sparkline/sparkline.js',  
          'resources/theme/dist/js/custom.js',
          'resources/js/custom.js'
     ], 'public/js/nice-admin.js')
     .copyDirectory('resources/theme/assets/images/', 'public/assets/images')
     .copyDirectory('resources/theme/dist/css/icons/material-design-iconic-font/fonts', 'public/fonts')
     .copy('node_modules/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css', 'public/css/daterangepicker.css')
     .copy('node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css', 'public/css/bootstrap-select.min.css')
     .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', {
           implementation: require('node-sass')
}).options({processCssUrls: false})
```

And then in my custom.js file I've just got this:

```
$(function() {
    "use strict";

    let date = moment().format();
    console.log(date);
});
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
app.js:13202 Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (nice-admin.js:2144)
    at mightThrow (app.js:12909)
    at process (app.js:12977)
```

I've verified that moment is in my compiled app.js file. So why can't my custom.js file see it, and what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Is your `custom.js` file being imported/required though your `app.js` file or is it completely separate?

Comment: It’s separate in the webpack file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're currently not assigning `moment` to anything. As per the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/webpack/), you should assign it to a variable to be used:

> var moment = require('moment');
> moment().format();

However, this will not work if you want to use it outside the scope of your `app.js` file. One way to do this would be to add it to the `window` object:

```
window.moment = require('moment');
```

Comment: Ok, this works. I was reading somewhere else that it's bad practice to attach things to the window object? I guess that's not the case?

Comment: @hyphen I think that was said to stop people just adding anything and everything to the window object just so they'd have access to it or because they could. For the sake of packages and libraries that you do want/need to have global access to then I'd say it's definitely the place to put it.